# How to apply indent correctly on a line containing BEGIN_C_DECLS macro?

Tags: c, indentation

I'm using `indent` utility to apply code styling on my code. I have problem with the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define BEGIN_C_DECLS extern "C" {
#define END_C_DECLS   }
#else /* !__cplusplus */
#define BEGIN_C_DECLS
#define END_C_DECLS
#endif /* __cplusplus */

BEGIN_C_DECLS 

int x;
...
END_C_DECLS
```

and after applying `indent -npro -kr -i8 -ts8 -sob -l80 -ss -ncs` I get:
 `BEGIN_C_DECLS int x` on the same line.

Any ideas how to keep them on separate lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since indent isn't a C parser (it can't be because it can't process `#include` directives), it uses heuristics to determine which tokens are identifiers or typedef names and which kind of syntactic unit these form. This obviously guesses wrong for what you are doing--mangling C syntax.

What you can do is to wrap the macros like so

```
/* *INDENT-OFF* */
BEGIN_C_DECLS
/* *INDENT-ON* */

int x;

/* *INDENT-OFF* */
END_C_DECLS
/* *INDENT-ON* */
```

Another way is through judicious use of the empty preprocessor directive, `#` (finally it becomes useful for *something*!):

```
#
BEGIN_C_DECLS
#
int     x;

#
END_C_DECLS
#
```